# How can I fetch all the array of images from folder using explode function?

Tags: php, mysql

**I am able to fetch only first image of every row of database.How can I fetch all the images using prepared statement and explode function.**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <?php 
     $sql="select property_img from img_tbl";

         $q=$conn->query($sql);
           if($q->num_rows>0)
           {
             while($r1=$q->fetch_assoc())
           {
                $property_img1=$r1['property_img'];
             $property_img2=explode(' ',$property_img1);


            echo '

         <div id="shade">
         <div class="col-sm-12 " id="color">
         <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">    

         <div class="row fppadd"> ';

         ?>

          <?php
            foreach($property_img2 as $data){

            echo  '<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/' . $data . '" width="200" height="150" alt="not fetched">&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            }

            ?> 
             <br></a></span><br>
         </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      </div> <?php
           }
           }?>       
           <br> 






      </form>
```

[uploads folder structure of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mCkP.png)

[Images are saved in database in this format.I want to fetch these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCFWd.jpg)

Comment: Simple. Don't store images in this format, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: Initialize array first it may be overwriting issue,
$property_img1 = array();
$property_img1=$r1['property_img'];
$property_img2=explode(' ',$property_img1);

Comment: The Ideal way to store Multiple Image is to create another table named `property_images` with the following fields `id`,`property_id`,`image_name`. And then fetch the image names from this table.

Comment: @Ketan Solanki   ..I stored the images in array format using implode function( already I have shared my DB snapshot) But my problem is to fetch the total Image(Array of images of all id's).

Comment: @Strawberry I want only in this format. My problem is only to fetching list of 'array of Images'

Comment: @Rits ..How can I reduce the overwriting issue?

Comment: Your problem is storing images in this format in a an RDBMS.

Comment: @ketansolanki id would serve no purpose in such a table

Comment: @Strawberry ..Later I have use of this property_id. please try on only  fetching of images. and more thing In the folder **Images are saved in looping format**.

Comment: what does `echo $q->num_rows;` print?

Comment: @Strawberry I am asking to store the Data with One to Many Relationship, That is for one property there will be many rows with individual Image name.For Eg id= 1, Property Id = 1,image_name= First.jpg and second record will be id=2, Property Id = 1,Image_name = Second.jpg

Comment: @sudha i did'nt  understand your question can you please explain me what you exactly want?

Comment: Previously I was doing this way..But I want to concise my data.so I used **implode** and **explode** function.Otherwise what is the use of these functions?   Am getting confuse. Pls clarify

Comment: Implode is just converting array of values to string by the provided character,
and the explode is opposite to that it taking string and using any character of that string we can convert it to array,
and you are using explode thats ok bt first you assigning your array to another array first time it is ok but second time there is and array of values, it creates problem thats why i am asking to initialize an array.

Comment: @ketansolanki I understand perfectly, and that is the correct approach, but a surrogate PK would not be useful in that instance

Comment: @Strawberry Ok then lets not debate on this topic ;P

Comment: @Rits ...**first see the snapshot of DB and uploads folder**. I saved the array of images. while saving in DB image name is original name ,but uploads folder images name comes inside the looping so it had been changed. I have to fetch the image what is stored inside the DB but am not able to fetch it(its changed because of looping)

Comment: Oh my god the problem is not in fetching, its in uploading image,
please first save your image in upload folder with you custom created name and then save that name also in database.
can i see ss of your uploading image code.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over the array after exploding by iterating array index :

```
for($i=0; $i<count($property_img2); $i++){
    echo  '<img class="img-zoom" src="uploads/' . $property_img2[$i] . '" width="200" height="150" alt="not fetched">&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

**However**, I agree with the comments that your design is poor, and you might consider changing it to one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Am getting same output as I have.It's also giving only first image of every property_id.I given the folder and Db snapshot.Please check that

Comment: In that case, you might have wrong data inserted. Try "print_r($property_img2);" in order to see what you really have saved in the database.

Comment: Array ( [0] => a.jpg [1] => avatar.png [2] => b.jpg )  . I got this output using "print_r($property_img2);"

Comment: Then everything is alright, just check if your pictures are being displayed with position absolute and they are showing on top of each other.